# MVC CRUD App Having Trouble Calling Post Method from Detail Page

Tags: model-view-controller, http-post, crud

I have a basic MVC CRUD app where I have setup my Views to use the basic Create/Edit/Delete templates. I am trying to add some JS to the Details page that is requiring manipulating some of the buttons and functionality. However, I am having trouble getting my button from the Details page to Post data to the DB and return to the index page. I wrote a custom method in the controller called "Approve", but am having some trouble calling it. I have what I believe to be the relative pieces of my controller and view below. I think a call to HttpPost Edit or the Approve methods would work, but it doesn't seem to want to stray away from the Details link when clicking. Would anyone be able to provide the best way to call either of these methods, resulting in posting to the DB and return to the Index. I have put the progress I am making in a couple of different buttons below and commented out. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Controller:

```
        // GET: Person/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            Person person = db.Person.Find(id);
            if (person == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(person);
        }

        // GET: Person/Create
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Person/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Person person)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Person.Add(person);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(person);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Person/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            Person person = db.Person.Find(id);
            if (person == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(person);
        }

        // POST: Person/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Person person)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(person).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(person);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Person/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            Person person = db.Person.Find(id);
            if (person == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(person);           
        }

        // POST: Person/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id, Person pers)
        {
            try
            {
                Person person = new Models.Person();
                // TODO: Add delete logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (id == null)
                        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                    person = db.Person.Find(id);
                    if (person == null)
                        return HttpNotFound();
                    db.Person.Remove(person);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(person);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Approve(int? id, Person person)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(person).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(person);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    <h4>Header</h4>

Read Only Informative Fields

<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @*<input type="submit" value="Approve" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default" />*@
                    <input type="submit" value="Approve" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Person", "Edit")'" class="btn btn-default" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default" />
   Added here ----> <a href="@Url.Action("Approve", "Person")">Test</a>
                    @*@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to have a form (with `action="@Url.Action("Approve","Person")"`) in which you will keep the values you want to submit ( the properties of Person object & Id - the param of your approve method). Then you use the normal form submit

Comment: So I added a link as illustrated above, which I can see is attempting to route to my Approve method. However, I am receiving a 404 error on the web page after clicking the link. I am wondering if its something in my Approve method? I copied it from Http Post Edit since the functionality is the same. Thanks for the response.

Comment: a link is different than a form. You need a form submit, not a link click!